# How can I pair values together from one text file and output the result to a separate file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this file called text.txt which looks like this:

```
type    iAtm    clust   prob    atoms         peak      pkppms
rbclust    0        5   0.84433 7.H2 8.H1' 7.67414 5.36287             pk5      7.85335 5.23688
rbclust    1        2   0.87237 7.H2 22.H1' 7.67414 5.59257            pk2      7.85285 5.52444
rbclust    2        3   0.96186 9.H2 10.H1' 7.43359 5.37814            pk3      7.45819 5.42587
rbclust    3        0   0.98187 9.H2 19.H1' 7.43359 5.69108            pk0      7.45766 5.68094
rbclust    4        4   0.78836 20.H2 8.H1' 7.60157 5.36287            pk4      7.89775 5.23989
rbclust    5        1   0.88374 21.H2 22.H1' 7.95925 5.59257           pk1      8.11276 5.52142
```

I want to grab the values from the `atom` columns which are a pair of atoms. For example, in the first row, the values in the atom columns are `7.H2 8.H1'` and I want to match them to the columns in the last two columns. For example, I would like my sample output for the first row (excluding the header) to look like this:

```
7.H2 7.85335
8.H1' 5.23688
```

and I would like my final output to look like this:

```
7.H2 7.85335
8.H1' 5.23688
7.H2 7.85285
22.H1' 5.52444
9.H2 7.45819
10.H1' 5.42587
9.H2 7.45766
19.H1' 5.68094
20.H2 7.89775
8.H1' 5.23989
21.H2 8.11276
22.H1' 5.52142
```

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

filename = 'text.txt'
match_file = sys.argv[1]

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = r'\s+')
df = df.ix[:. ['Atom','avgppm']]

match = pd.read_csv(match_file, sep = r'\s+', header = None, names = ('Atom', 'exp_ppm'))
```

I'm confused as to how I can match each atom with each value using pandas, how can I match this properly?

Edit:

```
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None 
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your input data really formatted like that?

If so, specifying all the columns makes it easier to read.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\sample_data\output\test.txt', sep=r'\s+', 
                 names=['type', 'iAtm', 'clust', 'prob', 'atom1','atom2',
                        'peak1', 'peak2', 'pkppms', 'match1', 'match2'],
                 skiprows=1, dtype=str)
```

Add cols, concat, sort, and write csv:

```
 pd.concat([(df.atom1 + ' ' + df.match1),
            (df.atom2 + ' ' + df.match2)]).sort_index().to_csv('out.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: I tried it and i get an error that says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` 
at the line `pd.concat([df.atom1+' ' + df.match1),(df.atom2+ ' ' +df.match2)]).sort_index().to_csv('out.txt', index = False)`

Comment: You are missing a "(" before "df.atom1".

Comment: sorry, I fixed that and it runs properly but when I look at the output all it says is: 
`None None`
`None None`
`None None`
`None None` ...

Comment: sorry, I'll edit the question so you can see what the 'out.txt' file looks like

Comment: Did you read it in like in my example? The resulting df should have a 0:len-1 index, not using any of the cols in the test.text.

Comment: No I read it in differently, like this: 
`df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep=r'\s+', names=['type', 'iAtm', 'clust', 'prob', 'atom1','atom2', 'peak1', 'peak2', 'pkppms', 'match1', 'match2'],skiprows=1, dtype=str, engine = 'python')`
is there a way I can make your code work with the way I read in the file?

Comment: Looks like the only difference is using the python engine. Is there a reason  you don't want the C engine?

Comment: no the other difference is that I'm reading in 'text.txt' in the beginning rather than the whole path that you listed out. and the reason I'm using the python engine is because I got a warning saying :

Comment: `match.py:7: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df =pd.read_csv(r'finalmatch.txt', sep = r'/s+', names = ['type','iAtm','clust','prob','atom1','atom2','peak1','peak2','pkppms','match1','match2'], skiprows=1, dtype=str)`

Comment: You have /s+ but you want \s+.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for such silly mistakes, I appreciate all your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using `zip()`:

```
zipped = zip(df.atoms.str.split(), df[["val1", "val2"]].values)
tmp = np.array([((a, val1), (b, val2)) for ((a, b), (val1, val2)) in zipped])
paired = []
for a, b in tmp:
    paired.append(a)
    paired.append(b)
pd.Series(paired)

0       [7.H2, 7.85335]
1      [8.H1', 5.23688]
2       [7.H2, 7.85285]
3     [22.H1', 5.52444]
4       [9.H2, 7.45819]
5     [10.H1', 5.42587]
6       [9.H2, 7.45766]
7     [19.H1', 5.68094]
8      [20.H2, 7.89775]
9      [8.H1', 5.23989]
10     [21.H2, 8.11276]
11    [22.H1', 5.52142]
dtype: object
```

If you actually want strings instead of a list of values (e.g. `9.H2 7.45819` instead of `[9.H2, 7.45819]`), change the `append()` lines to:

```
paired.append(' '.join(a))
paired.append(' '.join(b))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! i'm trying to implement this cod but I'm getting an error saying:
`Attribute Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'atoms'`
My `df is df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep = r'/s+') `
and i'm writing it out to a file like this: 
`df.to_csv('out.txt', index=False)`

Comment: Your example data has a column called `atoms`.  I did add `val1` and `val2` column names, as you don't have column names specified for the last two fields.  Check `df.columns` after `read_csv()`.  Does it match with the columns in your example data?